# Evaluate the probability that a reader of a magazine reads an ad and buys the advertised item

Tags: probability, statistics

A computer hardware company placed an ad for its new modem in a popular magazine.

The company believes that the ad will be read by 32% of the magazine's readers, and that 2% of those who read the ad will buy the modem.

With these assumptions, find the probability that a reader of the magazine will read the ad (event R) and buy the modem (event B).

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(R) = 32% = 0.32

P(B|R) = 2% = 0.02 (chance of buying modem, given they have read the ad)

The chance of both occurring together is, by the multiplication law of probability,
P(R ∩ B) = P (R) * P (B|R)
= 0.32 * 0.02
= 0.0064
= 0.64%